# do other kinds of sensors(except accelerometer)work when the screen is off on all android devices?

Tags: java, android, screen, sensors

as I was searching stackoverflow and google, I figured out that in some android phones, when the screen is turned off the accelerometer sensor works no more (e.g. [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982433/android-accelerometer-not-working-when-screen-is-turned-off?rq=1)). now I want to know about other kinds of sensors, I mean do other kinds of sensors, like proximity, work even when the screen is turned off in all devices or just like accelerometer senor it is based on the device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I searched more I figured out that this *bug* is not limited to accelerometer sensor and involves all kind of sensors, however it depends on the phone and OS version (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076834/proximity-sensor-not-working-with-screen-turned-off?rq=1) reports proximity sensor behavior in screen off)